# Kotlin: Make the function wait to return until for loop is complete

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple function that retrieves a value from Firebase Firestore. I want to return the value. How do I make the function wait until the value is retrieved, rather than immediately returning an empty value?

Please Kotlin only.

```
         fun fireStoreGetter(keyVal: String): String {
            Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "fGet running with keyVal: " + keyVal)
            //logs: FIRESTORE_OP: fGet running with keyVal: exampleString
            var userId :String = ""
            var mFirebaseDatabaseInstances = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            if (user != null) {
                userId = user.uid
                //Log.e(TAG, "User data is null")
            } else {
                Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "MUST AUTHENTICATE TO ACCESS FIRESTORE")
            }
            Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "USER IN WITH UID: " + userId)
            //logs FIRESTORE_OP: USER IN WITH UID: DGGiDibnldhP5z6iUyf_GQ
            val docRef2 = mFirebaseDatabaseInstances.collection("users").document(userId).collection("dBase").document("exampleDoc")
            docRef2.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                //for (document in result) {
                        if (document != null) {
                            //docVal is instantiated in main thread
                            docVal = document.getString(keyVal).toString()//String(keyVal)
                            Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "DOCVAL SET: " + docVal)
                            //logs: FIRESTORE_OP: DOCVAL SET: (correct value from firestore)
                        }
            }
        Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "RETURNING fGet: " + "VALUE: " + docVal)
        //logs: FIRESTORE_OP: RETURNING fGet: VALUE:       
        return docVal
        //returns empty
     }
```

Comment: You need to use a callback interface . or if you are using Kotlin  coroutines you can do it by `suspendCoroutine`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: @a_local_nobody, OP understands why value is empty, he asks how to wait for his listener execution

Comment: @VictorCold don't remember saying anything else, that's why it's a Q&A post to explain how to resolve it

Comment: There is no way you can return `docVal` as a result of a method. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a custom callback. You can also achieve that using Kotlin Coroutine as, as Kamal Nayan already mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below dependency to use `await()`

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
```

and use `suspend` keyword in the function name and add `.await()` after success or failure listener of firebase. This will make the code wait for the function to retrieve data from firebase.

[You can read this blog for reference](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-firebase-6f8577a3e00f)

**Your code should be like this:**

```
  suspend fun fireStoreGetter(keyVal: String): String {
        Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "fGet running with keyVal: " + keyVal)
        //logs: FIRESTORE_OP: fGet running with keyVal: exampleString
        var userId :String = ""
        var mFirebaseDatabaseInstances = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (user != null) {
            userId = user.uid
            //Log.e(TAG, "User data is null")
        } else {
            Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "MUST AUTHENTICATE TO ACCESS FIRESTORE")
        }
        Log.d("FIRESTORE_OP", "USER IN WITH UID: " + userId)
        //logs FIRESTORE_OP: USER IN WITH UID: DGGiDibnldhP5z6iUyf_GQ
        val docRef2 = mFirebaseDatabaseInstances.collection("users").document(userId).collection("dBase").document("exampleDoc")
        docRef2.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            //for (document in result) {
                    if (document != null) {
                        //docVal is instantiated in main thread
                        docVal = document.getString(keyVal).toString()
                    
                    }
        }
     return docVal
       }.await()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the actual implementation? I'm having a lot of issues trying to implement this.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Getting "Expecting member declaration" error regarding the last line --> }.await()

Comment: I tried this a few different ways. Still getting that "Expecting member declaration" error. I have never used a .await() after a function declaration like that. I added implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1' to my build.gradle and import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await in the script. Still same problems.

Comment: Kindly Share the log.

Comment: [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AlEJyRE7DfPctRjwKQfcq2XQy1XlbqLn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have another idea. you can use higher-order functions.      https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Comment: That doesn't seem like a worthwhile use of time if the suspend/await() approach you laid out above is actually legitimate.

Comment: Okay, I understand check the image provided in the below link, I have implemented with the await() -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1suhGo1bw3jK_BeO7l7FqIqqFDFjHkcPZ/view?usp=sharing    and I have highlighted the .await() which is at line -66

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how you try to do it now:

```
fun myFunction() {
    val value = fireStoreGetter(keyVal)
    ...
}

fun fireStoreGetter(keyVal: String): String {
    val docRef2 = ...
    docRef2.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        for (document in result) {
            if (document != null) {
                docVal = ...
            }
        }
    }
    return docVal
}
```

And this is how you should do it:

```
fun myFunction(value: String) {
    ...
}

fun fireStoreGetter(keyVal: String) {
    val docRef2 = ...
    docRef2.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        for (document in result) {
            if (document != null) {
                docVal = ...
            }
        }
        myFunction(docVal)
    }
}
```

Your `docRef2.get()` returns a Task instance. Which hasn't functions to wait for its result right in place, like in a suspend coroutine function or something like that. So the only way is not to return the result from `fireStoreGetter` function, but rather trigger `myFunction` when the result is ready.

**UPD**: Turns out there IS a way to wait for Task's result right in place. See [Kamal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67832254/9553363) answer if you really need to get rid of callbacks. But keep in mind that this will require a little extra tweaking. Coroutines, suspend functions, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's a good workaround. Hopefully I can get the above implementation from Kamal to work at some point. Until then I'll use this.